# Ubuntu 16.04 disk will not boot. I'm looking for help

Tags: boot

my Ubuntu 16.04 disk will not boot. I'm looking for help.
History of events:

1. The OS froze, so I turned off the computer and rebooted (I have 2 seperate disks on computer; one for Windows 10 and one for Linux; selectable via Grub2 boot menu)
2. Got "Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000200"
3. Used USB Live Ubuntu 16.04 to backup all data from the crashed disk.
4. Used Grub2 boot menu to select recovery mode; resulted in same Kernel panic error
5. Used Boot-Repair via USB Live Ubuntu 16.04; selecting "Recommended Repair" causes same Kernel panic error.
6. Used Boot-Repair "Create a Bootinfo Summary" to create a txt file for all to see; maybe it will help...but I don't see a way to attach the file to this post. It's a long file, so I won't paste it here, unless that's what's expected.

I have accessed and implemented internet search-based fixes to no avail.
Before doing a complete reinstall (as last resort), I'd really like to recover my system.

Comment: I would use a live media (eg. Ubuntu install media) to perform a `fsck` of your partition. I would also check the SMART data & confirm it's not a failing drive. *Also fyi: I wouldn't power-off unless absolutely necessary (did you try the sysreq-REISUB keys? or text terms?)*

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the super-fast reply @guiverc !!...I will look into your suggestions if this happens again so I don't shutdown needlessly.

Number 4 in the History of events (above) was the solution. I needed to select the recovery mode that was oldest, and then I was able to get my system back.